# Django formsets: Assign values before form/data is saved

Tags: django

I created a formset, which will be saved in the database afterwards. The formset has two fields 'ticket' & 'quantity'. In my model, there two additional fields 'order_reference' and 'ticket_name', which should be assigned before saving the form. Can you help me to achieve that?

models.py

```
class ReservedItem(models.Model):
    order_reference = models.CharField(
        max_length=10
        #unique=True
    )
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(
        Ticket,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='reserved_tickets'
    )
    ticket_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
def event_detail(request, event, organiser):
    queryset = Event.objects.filter(organiser__slug=organiser)
    event = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=event)

    tickets = []
    for ticket in Ticket.objects.all():
        tickets.append({'ticket': ticket})

    ReserveFormSet = formset_factory(ReserveForm, extra = 0)
    formset = ReserveFormSet(
        initial=tickets
        # Example with qty how tickets above looks [{'quantity': 1}, {'quantity': 4}, {'quantity': 2},]
        )

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ReserveFormSet(request.POST, initial=tickets)

        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                if form.cleaned_data['quantity'] > 0:

                    # QUESTION: How do I assign the values 'order_reference' & 'ticket_name' before saving the form in the database

                    form.save()
                    print("SAVED.")

    return render(request, 'events/event_detail.html', {'event': event, 'formset': formset})
```

forms.py

```
class ReserveForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ReservedItem
        fields = ['ticket', 'quantity']
```

Answer (score 3):

The moment I posted it, I found the solution in another post. The solution below. Sorry for the unnecessary post.

```
if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                if form.cleaned_data['quantity'] > 0:
                    obj = form.save(commit=False)
                    obj.ticket_name = 'ticket_name'
                    obj.order_reference = 'order_reference'
                    obj.save()
                    print("SAVED.")
```